# How TeslaUnread for Nova Launcher works?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hi am doing a project and I need to show off some social app (Facebook, Whatsapp) notification (unread count, not by the notification listener service) in my application. I tried in many ways, but I not able to get the answer and I see the "nova launcher" they are showing the exact notification unread by tesla Have any idea how [TeslsUnread](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw) works. I need to get the unread count for all the apps.

Comment: So you haven't looked at or tried anything yourself before starting a bounty?  This isn't a complete question. What is teslaunread? What isnt working?

Comment: @NickCardoso I tried manys ways after that only i posted question here